# Join table complicate

Tags: sql, join, left-join

i have these table

```
Person
ID_PRS   Name
------   -----
1        John
2        Brian
3        Mike

Con_PRS_Fonc
    ID_PRS  ID_FONCT  
    -----   -------
     1       17
     1       18
     3       17

   Fonction
       ID_FONCT   LABEL  ID_CATEG  ID_MET ID_ANA
       -------    -----  --------  ------ ------
         17       Boss      1        56     78
         18       Junior    1        45     56

Category
 ID_CATEG  LABEL
 --------  -----
    1      Cleaning
    2      Wahsing

MEtir
 ID_MET   LABEL
 ------   -----
  56       Go
  45       Come

Analys
 ID_ANA  LABEL
 ------  -----
  78     Think
  56     Drink
```

how can i get:

```
ID_PRS  NOM  ID_FONCT   LABEL_FONCT  ID_CATEG  LAB_CAT   ID_MET   LAB_MET   ID_AN   LAB_ANA
------  ---- --------   -----------  --------  -------    ------   -------   -----   -------
   1    John  17         Boss           1      Cleaning   56        GO        56     Think
```

i know only i can join the table Person with table Con_PRS_Fonc, but how can i join with other ?

```
SELECT * FROM PERSON
LEFT JOIN Con_PRS_Fonc ON PERSON.ID_PRS = Con_PRS_Fonc .ID_PRS
```

Thanks you in advance,
Stev

Comment: Suggestion: rename your multiple `LABEL` attributes with meaningful names that are unique throughout the model e.g. `Category_label`, `MEtir_label` and `Analys_label` respectively.

Comment: ...then your query would be very simple: `SELECT * FROM person NATURAL JOIN Con_PRS_Fonc NATURAL JOIN FONCTION NATURAL JOIN CATEGORY NATURAL JOIN MEtir NATURAL JOIN Analys;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you exactly what you want:

```
    SELECT 
Person.ID_PRS, 
Person.Name, 
Fonction.ID_FONCT, 
Fonction.LABEL AS LABEL_FONCT,
Fonction.ID_CATEG,
Category.LABEL AS LAB_CAT,
MEtir.ID_MET,
MEtirLABEL AS LAB_MET, 
Analys.ID_ANA,
Analys.LABEL AS LAB_ANS
FROM PERSON
INNER JOIN Con_Prs_Fonc ON Person.ID_PRS = Con_Prs_Fonc.ID_PRS
INNER JOIN Fonction ON Fonction.ID_FONCT = Con_Prs_Fonc.ID_FONCT
INNER JOIN Category ON Category.ID_CATEG = Fonction.ID_CATEG
INNER JOIN MEtir ON MEtir.ID_MET = Fonction.ID_MET
INNER JOIN Analys ON Analys.ID_ANA = Fonction.ID_ANA
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM person as P
INNER JOIN Con_PRS_Fonc AS CPF ON P.ID_PRS = CPF.ID_PRS 
INNER JOIN FONCTION AS FON ON FON.ID_FONCT = CPF.ID_FONCT
INNER JOIN CATEGORY AS C ON FON.ID_CATEG = C.ID_CATEG
INNER JOIN MEtir AS MEt ON Fon.ID_MET = MEt.ID_MET
INNER JOIN Analys AS ANA ON Fonc.ID_ANA = ANA.ID_ANNA
```

I can't confirm its 100% correct but just join the tables on the relationship :)